# How to render index in another index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a Model called Order.

I am using ActiveAdmin.

I have an index page for orders that the current user can see all of their orders.

I want another page that i call "production", that shows all of the orders, for a production manager to manage. Any thought on how to go about this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is the production manager going to have access to the active admin interface? Are you using something to handle different roles in the system?

Comment: yes the production manager has access to active admin. I am using can can to handle the roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another controller method say `ProductionController#something`, you can prepare the needed instance variables and then render the view of that index page. That's all.